# How to enable HugeTLB controller in cgroup v2 on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, cgroups, huge-pages

I am trying to enable [HugeTLB](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html#:%7E:text=1%20hca_object%3D23-,HugeTLB,-%C2%B6) Controller on cgroup v2 on my system but can't figure out  how.

This is the list of controllers on my system:

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.controllers 
cpuset cpu io memory pids rdma
```

And this is what I see for the meminfo on my system:

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
```

Am I missing something to enable the HugeTLB controller on cgroup v2? Is there a kernel flag, or some other setting that I need to enable?

Comment: did you *mount -t cgroup -o hugetlb none /sys/fs/cgroup* ?

Comment: That seems like the mount point for cgroup v1. Is there a similar mount point for cgroup v2?

Answer (score 0):

As you can read near to the bottom of the credited page, Control Group v2 does support the HugeTLB controller.

The difference with V1 being that all controllers which support v2 and are not bound to a v1 hierarchy **are automatically bound to the v2 hierarchy and show up at the root.**

No need for extra options to be specified as part of the mount command then and :

```
mount -t cgroup2 none $MOUNT_POINT
```

should suffice.

You can create some cgroup and check reading its associated `cgroup.controllers` file that the hugeTLB controller is available.

Of course (as any other controller) it is not activated by default.

---

Full credits to [kernel.org official documentation.](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Most distribution kernels will have this config option set, but if you have compiled your own kernel you might have missed the `CONFIG_CGROUP_HUGETLB` option.

You can check if your current kernel has this option enabled with

```
grep CONFIG_CGROUP_HUGETLB /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

if it doesn't print `CONFIG_CGROUP_HUGETLB=y` you need to recompile your kernel with this option.